# Что не так с замыканием?

Tags: php, функции, замыкания

Почему при единственном использовании все нормально работает а, если вызвать дважды функции все ломается?

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$arr2 = [3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 6, 1];
$arr3 = [1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 1];

function rob($ar){

  function fun($arr, $acc = 0) {
      if(max($arr) == null) {
         return $acc;

      }  else {
        $acc = $acc + max($arr);
        $key = array_search(max($arr), $arr);
        if ($key === 0) {
            $arr[$key] = null;
            $arr[$key + 1] = null;
            return fun($arr, $acc);

        } elseif ($key === (count($arr) - 1)) {
          $arr[$key] = null;
          $arr[$key - 1] = null;
          return fun($arr, $acc);

        } else {
          $arr[$key] = null;
          $arr[$key + 1] = null;
          $arr[$key - 1] = null;
          return fun($arr, $acc);

        }
      }
  }
  // return
  $a = fun($ar);
  return $a;
}



echo rob($arr1)."\n";
echo rob($arr2)."\n";
echo rob($arr3)."\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

То, что вы делаете, по сути не является замыканием. Фактически вы просто определяете функцию `fun` внутри `rob` и получаете ожидаемое:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare fun() (previously declared in ...

Правильный код может иметь вид:

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$arr2 = [3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 6, 1];
$arr3 = [1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 1];

function fun($arr, $acc = 0) {
    // ...
}

function rob($ar) {
    // Понятия не имею, зачем вам нужна эта функция-обертка
    return fun($ar);
}

echo rob($arr1)."\n"; // 6
echo rob($arr2)."\n"; // 11
echo rob($arr3)."\n"; // 9
```

Рабочий пример на [IDE One](https://ideone.com/pGF4Hx)

Comment: Я изначально так и написал, и этот вариант тоже не отработал так как надо и выдал те же ошибки...

Comment: Я вам привел ссылку на ideone и там все работает. Если у вас что-то не работает, то начните с обновления вопроса и добавления туда сообщения об ошибке. Иначе все это - гадание на кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 3):

> Все функции и классы PHP имеют глобальную область видимости - они могут быть вызваны вне функции, даже если были определены внутри и наоборот.
>
> PHP не поддерживает перегрузку функции, также отсутствует возможность переопределить или удалить объявленную ранее функцию.

http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.user-defined.php

Это означает, что единственная разница между

```
function a(){
    function b(){};
};
```

и

```
function a(){};
function b(){};
```

лишь в том, что функцию b в первом случае нельзя использовать до вызова функции `a`, и повторный вызов функции `a` вызовет ошибку

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ....

---

Два варианта решения:

1. Единожды объявить функцию `fun` вне `rob`
2. Использовать анонимные функции `$fun = function(){...}`

Comment: Я пробовал через анонимные функции, тоже не получалась. А так спасибо всем за ответы)